# Regiomontanus Triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

"If the base of a triangle and the opposite angle are known, and if we give or the height relative to the base or the area, then the sides can be determined". Regiomontanus proved it . How can I prove  ??

Comment: Why not use the proof that Regiomontanus gave?

Comment: The opposite vertex can only be on two circumference arcs supported on the base. This is because the angle is given. It also can only lie on two straight lines parallel to the base and at distance the height. Those arcs and the lines intersect at most in four points, but those points are symmetric with respect to the base and with respect to the perpendicular bisector of the base. So, the three solutions are congruent triangles.

Answer (score 1):

For triangle $ABC$, suppose

- Side length $c$ is known.$\\[4pt]$

  Angle $C$ is known.$\\[4pt]$

  The area $k$ is known.

From the area formula $k=\frac{1}{2}ab\sin(C)$ we can find $ab$.

Then from the law of cosines $c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos(C)$ we can find $a^2+b^2$.

Without loss of generality, assume $a\ge b$.

From the identities
\begin{align*}
(a+b)^2&=a^2+2ab+b^2\\[4pt]
(a-b)^2&=a^2-2ab+b^2\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
we can find $a+b$ and $a-b$, and then we can easily solve for $a,b$.